# Blender Material Color in Mitsuba (or any other) Shader

Tags: python, materials

I have imported a large WRL file (contains >3000 parts) with colors included (*one* material for each part!).
In Cycles and Blender-Render, the colors are rendered just fine.

But what do I do if I want Mitsuba, Luxrender or Yafaray as renderer?
Is there a way to get the Blender-material-color and put that in a 3rd-party material?

I know how to make a material with python and apply it to a mesh. But how do I **get** the color of the selected object's blender-material?

*How to make a Mitsuba, Luxrender or Yafaray matrial is one thing I yet have to find out too.*

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Luxrender and Yafaray provide addons for blender which allow the creation of their respective materials from Blender's GUI.

Comment: Like the "Convert to" button? Yes, unfortunately this does not work :-\

Comment: More like an interface specifically designed for creating a material for whichever render engine

Comment: For BI you can get the diffuse color with `bpy.data.materials["Material Name"].diffuse_color`. Cycles is trickier due to its node-based nature.

Comment: Right! But I've imported a WRL with the correct color from CAD. It creates a Blender material with the color from CAD. Now I need ot get this color with python. How can I do that?

Comment: Ok! That might help! `bpy.data.materials["Material Name"].diffuse_color`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the mat color from Blender Internal material like so:

```
# from material
mat = bpy.data.materials['Material_Name']
color = mat.diffuse_color

# or from object
ob = bpy.context.active_object
if len(ob.data.materials):
    # get 1st material slots material
    mat = ob.data.materials[0]
else:
    # no slots
    print("No Material")
    mat = None
if mat:
    color = mat.diffuse_color
```

To change LuxRenders material diffuse color:

```
mat.luxrender_material.luxrender_mat_matte.Kd_color = color
```

Mitsuba:

```
mat.mitsuba_material.mitsuba_bsdf_diffuse.reflectance_color = color
```

In Yafaray there is no need to change anything, it will use:

```
mat.diffuse_color
```

Answer (score 3):

Here we go!
After a few tries it works!

```
import bpy

if bpy.context.selected_objects != []:
    for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        if ob.type == 'MESH':
            objcolor = ob.active_material.diffuse_color
            ob.active_material.mitsuba_material.mitsuba_bsdf_diffuse.reflectance_color = objcolor
            ob.active_material.luxrender_material.luxrender_mat_matte.Kd_color = objcolor
```

This is it! Select all objects and run this script. The diffuse color will be added to Mitsuba and Luxrenderer.

Comment: Nice usage of active_material! If my answer helped and you figured it out pls mark it as correct;)